# How to send a link to users in same wifi network?

Tags: android, wifi

I want to send a link or page to every user in my wifi network. I have a store and i provide free wifi to my customers and i want to show a OFFER page to all the customers using my network. I know bit coding and i want to build it myself but have no idea how or where to start. so, if someone gives a detail explanation. I hope it would be a help for many others like me

Comment: This question isn't a good (or on-topic) one for the format of Stack Overflow. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for examples of on-topic and off-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

Many Wifi routers have a "welcome page" setting where people connecting to that particular network are shown this page where they have to click a button or accept terms before being able to use the internet. Check your wifi router's manual to see if it has such a feature.